# User directory does not exist when logging in via ssh to a Synology NAS

Tags: ssh, synology, home-directory, administrative-privileges, dsm

On a Synology NAS with DSM 7.0 I have created through the Graphical UI a dedicated admin user (as recommended in Synology's setup procedure), then I have enabled ssh login and now I can ssh into the Synology. So far so good. However when logging in via ssh I get a strange message before the prompt appears:

```
Could not chdir to home directory /var/services/homes/<my-admin-user>: No such file or directory
```

Why's this happening? Is the DSM 7 operation system of my NAS not properly configured?

And how do I fix it? Do I just create the user's home directory?

#### Additional info

The path `/var/services/homes` exists, but it is a symlink to `/volume1/@fake_home_link` which does not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to "Control Panel > User & Group > Advanced > User Home" and check "Enable user home service" before persisting it with "Apply".

Answer (score 0):

This error message indicates that the system is unable to change to the specified home directory for the specified user, because the directory does not exist.
It could be that the folder `/var/services/homes/<my-admin-user>` is missing or the user might not have permission to access the directory. It could also be that the directory is spelled incorrectly.

You should check if the directory path exists and if the user have the permission to access it, if not you can create the directory and give the user permission to access it.

Answer (score -2):

amazin GIST for DSM 6, 7
https://gist.github.com/seignovert/c903c2facbf88243dac90de68be696ea

Works for me:
DSM: 7
Client: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS